# MvcUriComponentsBuilder and inccorect binding in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

### Code

I have my *Controller* method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/{userId}/{configId}")
def edit(@PathVariable("userId") User user,
         @PathVariable("configId") Configuration configuration) {
    /* some code here*/
}
```

When I call this method from my browser it works very well, and user, and configuration args bind from DataBase by their id.

### Problem

But, when I used `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` class, I got some exceptions for incorrect arguments type in the expected method.

```
MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(MyController.class, "edit", 1, 2).build()
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source to convert from must be an instance of @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable User; instead it was a java.lang.Long
```

**Faced some body with similar problem? Are there any solution?**

**NOTE**: I'm currently using Spring Web MVC 4.1.8.RELEASE

### A bit more descriptions

I'm using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` in Thymeleaf template like this:

```
th:action="${#mvc.url('CC#edit').arg(0, configuration.access.id).arg(1, configuration.id).build()}
```

As docs says that in `arg` method should be passed native method arg (in my example should passed `User` and `Configuration` instances). But, in my opinion better solution is using long values (for example) and then autobind it to object as it expected (as like it works over browser call)

### Additional info!

I listened to [@Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis), and use this function as it described in it docs

```
th:action="${#mvc.url('CC#edit').arg(0, configuration.access.user).arg(1, configuration).build()
```

Passed arguments are correct in this example.

***BUT***, I have gotten exception **AGAIN**!

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute ua.smartsteamshop.web.app.domain.User to type java.lang.String
```

***It is looks like a bug! Guys, I need your help! This question should be discussed!***

Comment: Why are you passing 1 and 2 as arguments? What does the javadoc for the `fromMethodName` say?

Comment: Ok, docs says that this are nativ method args, but how should I fill it similar to `expand` method. I'll say more. I'm using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` in Thymeleaf template like this:
`th:action="${#mvc.url('CC#edit').arg(0, configuration.access.id).arg(1, configuration.id).build()}`

Comment: I don't think that it is the best solution passing user and config into model and then build url using it as args, in my opinion better solution it is using long values (for example) and then autobind it to object as it expected

Comment: I'm really interested in where you got the idea from that `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` is an appropriate tool for this task.

Comment: I`m not sure that I correctly understand your comment, can you add a bit more description

Comment: It's been too long, but still... Have you tried feeding no (or null) arguments to `fromMethodName(..)` and doing `buildAndExpand` later as in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-links-to-controllers ?

Comment: @FlasHfromRu Thanks for response. I made some workaround, but I will check your solution